# Subsonic 3 - Namespace hidden - Probably me

Tags: c#, vb.net, subsonic, namespaces, subsonic3

It's Friday so I'm prob doing something stupid here. In fact I'd put money on it.

I'm playing around with Subsonic - got my feet happily into v2.2 but intrigued by v3 alpha

Followed Rob's webcast, did as he did, watched T4 generate the code, went to use the new namespace and oh. No namespace.

I can see the namespace Test.Data in each of the generated .cs files, the tt files are included in the project as is *subsonic.dll*, there are no errors (I managed to get rid of a warning for the duplicate directives) but I just can't see the namespace.

To test it out I am building a simple *vb.net* console application so wondering if there is a conflict there. Using v2.2 against the same db works fine.

Ready for you to point and laugh.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, as I thought, me being a Friday n00b.

Didn't realise until now that you can't have vb.net and c# code co-existing in anything other than a asp.net project.

Will split into separate assemblies and go from there.

"Nothing to see here, please move along.."

Have a good weekend.

Ed

Comment: See now, I didn't know you could mix C# and VB even an asp.net project.  Hooray for learning from mistakes!